# Add Bazel to a docker image

Tags: docker, bazel

We are migrating an existing project to Bazel, and we are facing the following situation:

The project is rather large, and we want to transition gradually; during that gradual transition both our old build approach and Bazel should work; our current system creates docker images out of our project and then runs tests and other validations in those docker containers. So to add Bazel, we seem to have to be able to run Bazel inside those docker containers as well.

Is there a way to add Bazel into existing docker files such that we don't download the components we don't need to download, and such that we can store the resulting image in our company's repository?

By now, I have seen a lot of instructions on how to build docker images using bazel and I have also found an old bazel image by google with lots of tools we don't need, and the repository itself had been archived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do something like that. While you could just copy paste in the installation instructions into an Ubuntu Docker file, I'd strongly recommend using [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk). e.g. something like this should work (untested);

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# NOTE 'g++ unzip zip' are required by bazel
RUN apt update && apt install wget g++ unzip zip

RUN wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.15.0/bazelisk-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod 755 bazelisk-linux-amd64 && \
    mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/bazelisk

# Download some of the other tools that you explicitly need...

RUN mkdir /workspace

WORKDIR /workspace

USER bazel

# other setup...
```

Now to get the most out of bazelisk, you'll need to add a file `.bazelversion` to your workspace. e.g.

```
6.0.0
```

Now when you run bazelisk (e.g. `bazelisk build //...` from your docker container bazelisk will;

- Download and extract bazel version 6.0.0
- Run bazel 6.0.0 and build all targets under `//...`

NOTE: Bazel does depend on some system deps, which won't be covered by the bazelisk install. But you can choose which system deps you will likely use with bazel.

Comment: "Bazelisk will download and extract bazel" -- this is what I would prefer to avoid. I would like to be able to install the required bazel version and then push the image to our company repo, so that the CI process does not get longer during the transition period. 
I have followed the instructions on installing bazel directly, but now I run into `/usr/bin/env: "python3" no such file or dir`, even though our image is based on python-slim and when i do `docker run --user bazel <sha> /usr/bin/env python3 -c \"print('hello')\""`, it works.

Comment: "this is what I would prefer to avoid", that's fair. If that's the case, I would instead recommend following [the ubuntu install guide](https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu#add-dis-uri). Keep the `.bazelversion`, in your workspace, instead of downloading the version specified it'll instead just produce an error if you system installed version is different. Perhaps it would be better to start off with an ubuntu or debian base image and let apt install the python version that Bazel depends on?

Comment: We ended up doing it exactly like you suggested, after all, bazel is then installed from the local infrastructure and it makes almost no difference